# How to auto fill a textbox from a comobobox using a textfile

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I 'm currently creating a form in VB that uses a text file to gather information for a combo box then automatic use the next word in the text file that's comma delimited to automatically populate a textbox.
But the current code I wrote show the list for the combo box but always auto fills the textbox with the second word on the second line and will not change the textbox after i select another option from the combo box  can someone help?

Sorry if this isn't very clear.

My Text file is in this format:

Robert,5 BellView Road

Martin,6 BellView Road

Ect....

My code is as follows:

Dim LineString As String

Dim FieldString As String()

```
    Try

        Dim ContactInfoStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\temp\test1.txt")

        Do Until ContactInfoStreamReader.Peek = -1

            LineString = ContactInfoStreamReader.ReadLine()
            FieldString = LineString.Split(CChar(","))
            LineString = FieldString(0)
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(LineString)
            Loop
        RichTextBox2.Text = FieldString(1)
        ContactInfoStreamReader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("""Customers Name & Address.txt"" file was not found")
    End Try
```

Comment: Why not use: `File.ReadAllLines()` and then just use a `For Each Line`?

Comment: Exactly what do you want to do with text box when the comboBox value is changed? Do you want to load the next value of comboBox to the textbox ?

Comment: I want it to take the value after the comma for example if I choose Robert in the combo box I want the text box to have 5 BellView Road but if I choose martin I want it to display 6 BellView Road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know you have provided code, however this is how I would do it.
First of all we make a `Person` [Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx) and create a `Person List` to store each `Person`
After that we read / load the text file into a `string array` and then we use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq) to split the text files line where the comma is and have it sort the name and address into two keys one being `NAME` and the other being `ADDRESS`.
 Once that is done we loop through each of the items and create a new `Person` with the values `value.NAME` and `Value.Address` for the persons name and address as well as add the person's name into a `combobox`
and finally we add a [ComboBox Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox_events(v=vs.110).aspx) that changes the `Textbox's` text to the selected `ComboBox's Index` that matches the `List of People` that was created to store each `Person`

```
Public Class Form1
Dim People As New List(Of Person)

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    Try
        TextBox1.Text = People(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex).address
    Catch
        ''this will prevent errors if there is a name with no address
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ''This is the location I used, feel free to change it here.
    Dim location As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Dim fileName As String = "test1.txt"
    Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(location, fileName)

    Dim query = From line In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
                Let val = line.Split(",")
                Select New With {Key .NAME = val(0), Key .ADDRESS = val(1)}

    For Each value In query
        Dim p = New Person(value.NAME, value.ADDRESS)
        People.Add(p)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(value.NAME)
    Next

    ''ADD OTHER COMBOBOX ITEMS HERE IF NEED BE, SO EVERYTHING IS IN ORDER
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("ANDREW")
End Sub
End Class

Class Person
Public Property name() As String
Public Property address() As String
Public Sub New(name As String, address As String)
    Me.name = name
    Me.address = address
End Sub
End Class
```

EDIT:
This is how I formatted the text file.
`Robert,5 BellView Road`
 
`Martin,6 BellView Road`

Comment: Hi, I have just tried this out but I still having a problem the above sorts the combo box correctly but when I select the name it throw up an error when trying to write to the text box. (Argument Out Of Range Exception) it does this a this stage of the code. Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    TextBox1.Text = People(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex).address
End Sub

Comment: Do you have the text files information one line after the other?

Comment: Yes the format is like this:

Line 1: Robert,5 BellView Road
Line 2: Martin,6 BellView Road

Comment: Have you got any other names in the combo box?

Comment: Not ATM but I will be adding up to 50 when I can get it working.

Comment: Brilliant that worked perfectly thanks for all your help :)